# Anti-theft through high frequency oscillating curcuits

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics, oscillators, electrical-engineering, electromagnetic-induction

As far as I know the anti-theft chips used in malls ([see here](http://www.wellguardcn.com/sale-1683112-customized-eas-rf-hard-tag-black-white-for-zara-h-m-clothing.html)) are basically high frequency (8.2 MHz) oscillating curcuits that resonate when stimulated by an external field (the two pillars at the exit) so the amplitude improves and triggers an alarm signal.

I wanted to build this at home. As for the antennas I used two coils. One of which I feed a 8.2 MHz current (about 9-15V) with a function generator. The other one is just connected to an osci where I can see whether the amplitude changes. Unfortunately it doesn't work and I wonder why.

At this point I want to mention that I've tried this with a self built oscillating curcuit (coil with 3mH and Conductor with 10 nF) with a resonance frequency of 29 kHz and it worked perfectly. So which effects come into play at higher frequencies which stop me from seeing any change on the osci?

Here you can see a picture of what I expected to happen:[image: Conducting Curcuit]
I assume that the one who took those photos just switched the V/div-scale on the osci to make it look like something happened because I basically do the ecaxt same thing and nothing happens.

Comment: Doesn't sound like your circuit is all that complicated, but it would still be nice if you supplied a schematic to serve as a point of reference for discussions. As for the difference in response when doing your test at 29 kHz versus 8.2 MHz, offhand one thought that comes to mind might be that your 29 kHz test used a resonant circuit and your 8.2 MHz circuit apparently did not. A high-Q resonance circuit can be a good basis for a sensitive detector because very small changes in L or C can move the circuit off the large resonance peak.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't seem to have enough reputation points to provide a schematic as a second image in my post. And I couldn't find out how to put a picture in a comment like this.
For now I will try to build a resonant circuit with 8.2 MHz and if that works I can be sure that the chip from the mall is something different. I will edit edit this comment as soon as this is done.